# Creating a google store locator using php and sql

Tags: php, sql, google-maps, search

I am using the following guide to create a store locator using google maps: https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3

So far I am not getting any errors, but I am not able to display the data in my database as an XML as it should. Instead it is displaying the following:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<locations/>
```

It is only showing the end of what the document should look like, but it is not returning any of the data.

This is the code I have so far:

```
<?php
require("dbinfo.php");

// Get parameters from URL
$center_lat = $_GET["lat"];
$center_lng = $_GET["lng"];
$radius = $_GET["radius"];

// Start XML file, create parent node
$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");
$node = $dom->createElement("locations");
$parnode = $dom->appendChild($node);

// Opens a connection to a mySQL server
$connection=mysql_connect ($hostname, $username, $password);
if (!$connection) {
  die("Not connected : " . mysql_error());
}


// Set the active mySQL database
$db_selected = mysql_select_db($database, $connection);
if (!$db_selected) {
  die ("Can\'t use db : " . mysql_error());
}

// Search the rows in the locations table
$query = sprintf("SELECT address, name, lat, lng, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('%s') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians('%s') ) + sin( radians('%s') ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM locations HAVING distance < '%s' ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20",
  mysql_real_escape_string($center_lat),
  mysql_real_escape_string($center_lng),
  mysql_real_escape_string($center_lat),
  mysql_real_escape_string($radius));
$result = mysql_query($query);

$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {
  die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());
}

header("Content-type: text/xml");

// Iterate through the rows, adding XML nodes for each
while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  $node = $dom->createElement("locations");
  $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);
  $newnode->setAttribute("name", $row['name']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("address", $row['address']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("lat", $row['lat']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("lng", $row['lng']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("distance", $row['distance']);
}

echo $dom->saveXML();
?>
```

My table name is 'locations'.

I was previously getting sql errors but managed to get passed them by correcting the database connection mistakes that i previously made so I am sure it is connected to the database.

Any help or advice is appreciated.

Thanks

Mike

Comment: Note that mysql_* are deprecated. You should use mysqli_* instead. Also it is good practice to put exit() function after header() call, because script won't stop executing after header() is called.

Comment: What values are you using for `$center_lat`,`$center_lng` and `$radius`?  Does your database contain data in that area?  Do you get a response if you make the radius large enough to cover the whole earth?

Comment: @geocodezip the data for $center_lat, $center_lng are taken from the database. The value for $radius is set on like 26 with the number 3959 (the number of miles for radius of the world)

Comment: @whirlwind Yeah i thought that so changed them all to mysqli but this caused me to get errors so i changed them back to mysql to try and get it to display the xml for now

Answer (score 0):

Your code is ok. The main problem is that google provided in this link https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3  the sample location that do not contain address within 25 radius.
So you need to change the radius from 25 to 28 or 30 in URL

```
phpsqlsearch_genxml.php?lat=37&lng=-122&radius=28
```

Although may be you have some error in your code. So that I am providing my code here.

```
<?php
require("phpsqlsearch_dbinfo.php");

// Get parameters from URL
$center_lat = $_GET["lat"];
$center_lng = $_GET["lng"];
$radius = $_GET["radius"];

// Start XML file, create parent node
$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");
$node = $dom->createElement("markers");
$parnode = $dom->appendChild($node);


// Search the rows in the markers table
$query = sprintf("SELECT address, name, lat, lng, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('%s') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians('%s') ) + sin( radians('%s') ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM markers HAVING distance < '%s' ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20",
  mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$center_lat),
  mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$center_lng),
  mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$center_lat),
  mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$radius));
$result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
if (!$result) {
  die("Invalid query: " . mysqli_error($connection));
}

header("Content-type: text/xml");

// Iterate through the rows, adding XML nodes for each
while ($row = @mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
  $node = $dom->createElement("marker");
  $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);
  $newnode->setAttribute("name", $row['name']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("address", $row['address']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("lat", $row['lat']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("lng", $row['lng']);
  $newnode->setAttribute("distance", $row['distance']);
}

echo $dom->saveXML();
?>
```

This will solve your problem definitely.

If you want the complete store locator code then write in comment.